# Command doing the same job as StrBefore but being expandable

Tags: macros, expansion, xstring

I am looking for a command allowing me to get 3 as output if the input is 3.2. `\StrBefore{3.2}{.}` works fine for this purpose but is not expandable and I need to call it in another macro inside a `\setcounter` command where it is expected to have a number and then to expand the `\StrBefore` command. Is there a work around using `\StrBefore` or do I need a different function and which one?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcounter{try}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\StrBefore{#1}{.}}

\newcommand\test[1]{\setcounter{try}{\foo{#1}}%
\arabic{try}}

\begin{document}

Result of foo\{3.2\}: \foo{3.2}
Result of test\{3.2\}: \test{3.2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One approach is using the optional argument of `StrBefore`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{try}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\StrBefore{#1}{.}[\result]}

\newcommand\test[1]{\foo{#1}\setcounter{try}{\result}\arabic{try}}%


\begin{document}

Result of foo\{3.2\}: \foo{3.2}
Result of test\{3.2\}: \test{3.2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Another approach would be to parse it yourself, without needing any assignments (except in the preamble to define `\foo` and a helper macro):

```
\documentclass{book}

%\usepackage{xstring}
%\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\StrBefore{#1}{.}}

\makeatletter
\def\fooex#1.#2\@nil{#1}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\fooex #1.\@nil}
\makeatother

\newcounter{try}
\newcommand\test[1]{\setcounter{try}{\foo{#1}}%
\arabic{try}}

\begin{document}

Result of foo\{3.2\}: \foo{3.2},
Result of foo\{32\}: \foo{32},

Result of test\{3.2\}: \test{3.2}

\end{document}
```

Updated using suggestions from Jonathan: pass an extra `.` to the helper macro so that something sensible happens when the input string doesn't contain one; use `\@nil` instead of `\relax` as the 'special token', now needing `\makeatletter` protection, as LaTeX itself uses `\@nil` for similar purpose and it is less likely to appear in the argument (and if it does, is more likely to generate a meaningful error).

Comment: +1, sorry I didn't notice this answer when I posted, I deleted mine (which was identical, more or less)

Comment: you could make your `\fooex` safer by something like `\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\getfirst#1..\@nil}
\def\getfirst#1.#2.#3\@nil{#1}`. This also works for cases like `\foo{32}`.

Comment: @Jonathan: thanks, I have updated my answer using something similar to your suggestion, but I am not sure why you suggest adding an extra dotted component?

Comment: @cyberSingularity you're right, of course. The extra dot is only needed if you also want to work with `#2` which always contains a trailing dot in this case ....

Comment: you could replace `\@nil` by `\fooex` itself, thus avoiding the `\makeatletter`.

Comment: @jfbu: thanks, that would certainly work. However, I will not merge this into the answer as I feel that the current version is easier to read, in a sense. Please retain your comment here for the benefit of others though!

Answer (score 2):

This is the `stringstrings` approach.  Things to know about it:

`[q]` is quiet mode, `[v]` is verbose mode.  The package stores results of string manipulations in the expanded result `\thestring`, and results of string "queries" in  `\theresult`.  So in the macro `\test`, you can do whatever you want with the expanded `\thestring` (in this case, I just print it).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{stringstrings}

\newcounter{tempdot}

\newcommand{\foo}[2][v]{%
  \whereischar[q]{#2}{.}%
  \setcounter{tempdot}{\theresult}%
  \addtocounter{tempdot}{-1}%
  \substring[#1]{#2}{1}{\thetempdot}%
}

\newcommand\test[1]{%
  \foo[q]{#1}%
  \thestring%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Result of foo\{3.2\}: \foo{3.2}\\
Result of test\{3.2\}: \test{3.2}

\end{document}
```