# How can I embed xstring commands (with commands as tokens) within other xstring commands?

Tags: strings

I'd like to manipulate strings.

The following `hello_en.txt` should become `hello`.

This is related to, and quite possibly a duplicate of, [Command doing the same job as StrBefore but being expandable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133422/command-doing-the-same-job-as-strbefore-but-being-expandable). The problem there did not really  solve mine, however.

## Example

I tried putting an `\expandafter` before the first `\StrBefore`, but it did not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand\mystring{hello\_en.txt}
\begin{document}
\StrBefore{\StrBefore{\mystring{}}{.}}{\_} % more complex DOES NOT WORK
\StrBefore{\StrBefore{hello\_en.txt}{.}}{\_} % simpler DOES NOT WORK
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use something expandable, which `\StrBefore` isn't, and also be careful about the number of expansions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand\mystring{hello\_en.txt}

\begin{document}

\expandarg
\StrBefore{\mystring}{.}[\temp]          
\StrBefore{\temp}{\noexpand\_}

\end{document}
```

The default of `xstring` is `\fullexpandarg`, which is to be neutralized as fully expanding `\_` is not something one wants in these cases.

If you try `\edef\tmp{\_}` you get, as replacement text,

```
\protect\global\let\\textunderscore\unhbox\voidb@x\kern .06em\vbox{\hrule width.3em}\\textunderscore
```

or, if you have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`,

```
\protect\T1\textunderscore
```

so in both cases it's not what you want `\StrBefore` to look for.

Comment: Just for educational purposes, could you add what a fully expanded `\_` is?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a job for [`l3regex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/l3regex) to me

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \regexreplace \regex_replace_all:nnN
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand\mystring{hello\_en.txt}
\begin{document}
\regexreplace{\c{_}.*}{}\mystring
\show\mystring
\end{document}
```

(In the regex, `\c{_}` is a control sequence matching exactly `\_` while `.*` is standard regex syntax for 'any character'.)

Comment: Thats funny because in the real document I am using ExplSyntax (LaTeX3). This question stems from iterating files: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254247/how-can-i-iterate-over-a-paragraph-delimited-list-in-latex. I have a bunch of documents with ISO 639-1 language suffixes (en, de, etc.). They are contained in a master folder with the same name of the files but without the language suffix or extension.

Comment: @macmadness86 If you have a clear pattern for the names then a classical delimited macro will be the most efficient approach.

Comment: Your answer is my favorite, but I must mark egreg's answer, because it fits the question more accurately.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `stringstrings`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\newcounter{tmpctr}
\newcommand\preunderscore[1]{%
  \whereischar[q]{#1}{_}%
  \setcounter{tmpctr}{\theresult}%
  \addtocounter{tmpctr}{-1}%
  \substring{#1}{1}{\thetmpctr}%
}
\begin{document} 
\def\mystring{hello_en.txt}
\preunderscore{\mystring} is the truncated text.
\end{document}
```

If one wanted to specify the name with a quoted underscore, a small change is needed (which assumes there are no `@` characters in the filename):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\newcounter{tmpctr}
\newcommand\preunderscore[1]{%
  \convertchar[q]{#1}{\_}{@}%
  \whereischar[q]{\thestring}{@}%
  \setcounter{tmpctr}{\theresult}%
  \substring{#1}{1}{\numexpr\thetmpctr-1}%
}
\begin{document} 
\def\mystring{hello\_en.txt}
\preunderscore{\mystring} is the truncated text.
\end{document}
```