# Why does nesting some xstring commands causes errors?

Tags: errors, strings, xstring, nesting, combine

Why does combining some command of the [xstring package](https://ctan.org/pkg/xstring?lang=en) causes errors? e.g. when I compile the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
    \StrCompare{\StrChar{bbbb}{4}}{\StrChar{aaaa}{3}}% are 4th character of first argument with 3th character of second argument differ ---> result 1 (yes and in first position)
\end{document}
```

it return the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\xs_StrChar__ ...ef \xs_arg_ii {#2}\edef \xs_call 
                                                  {\noexpand \xs_testopt {\n...
l.5 ...mpare{\StrChar{bbbb}{4}}{\StrChar{aaaa}{3}}
                                                  % are 4th character of fir...

?
```

Comment: Because (most) `xstring`'s commands are not expandable, so they can't be nested. You need to do in separate steps, something like `\StrChar{bbbb}{4}[\resultA]`, then `\StrChar{aaaa}{3}[\resultB]`, and then `\StrCompare{\resultA}{\resultB}`. The application is different, but the solution is basically the same as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133422/134574)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a rather common problem using `xstring` because (most of) its commands don't work in expansion-only contexts (Inside an `\edef` or `\expanded` or `\write` or. . .), so each command has to execute completely before the next one starts. In short, they can't be nested. A simpler example that would show the same problem would be to define:

```latex
\newcommand\ifequal[2]{%
  \def\tempa{#1}%
  \def\tempb{#2}
  \ifx\tempa\tempb
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
```

and then use the command inside an `\edef`:

```latex
\edef\test{\ifequal{abc}{abc}{true}{false}}
```

which would throw the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\ifequal #1#2->\def \tempa 
                           {#1}\def \tempb {#2} \ifx \tempa \tempb \expandaf...
l.13 \edef\test{\ifequal{abc}{abc}
                                  {true}{false}}
?
```

however if you used it outside the `\edef` it would work.

To allow using the results of one `xstring` command in another, most of the commands have a final optional argument, which is a macro to store the result of the processing, then you need to do each step separately and collect the result at each step:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\StrChar{bbbb}{4}[\tempA]
\StrChar{aaaa}{3}[\tempB]
\StrCompare{\tempA}{\tempB}
\end{document}
```

Hopefully soon I'll finish my expandable version of `xstring` ;-)

Comment: Are you Christian Tellechea? or you want to write your own package?

Comment: @C.F.G No, I'm not Christian :-) I'm midway through writing a string manipulation package with more or less the same feature set as `xstring`, but with all commands expandable.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `\StrChar` in the argument of `\StrCompare`.

Here are two implementations: one with `xparse` and `expl3`, one with `xstring`. Note that the former is completely expandable, the latter isn't.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring} % for comparison

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\comparestringitems}{mmmmmm}
 {
  % #1 = first string
  % #2 = item number
  % #3 = second string
  % #4 = item number
  % #5 = true text
  % #6 = false text
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \str_item:nn { #1 } { #2 } } { \str_item:nn { #3 } { #4 } } { #5 } { #6 }
 }

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_eq:nn { ee } { TF,T,F,p }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\comparestringitemsxstring}[6]{%
  \StrChar{#1}{#2}[\compareA]%
  \StrChar{#3}{#4}[\compareB]%
  \StrCompare{\compareA}{\compareB}[\compareC]
  \ifnum\compareC=0 #5\else#6\fi
}

\begin{document}

\comparestringitems{aaaa}{4}{bbbb}{3}{true}{false}

\comparestringitems{aaaa}{4}{bbab}{3}{true}{false}

\comparestringitemsxstring{aaaa}{4}{bbbb}{3}{true}{false}

\comparestringitemsxstring{aaaa}{4}{bbab}{3}{true}{false}

\edef\test{\comparestringitems{aaaa}{4}{bbab}{3}{true}{false}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a simple modification, you can also pass macros to `\comparestringitems`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\comparestringitems}{mmmmmm}
 {
  % #1 = first string
  % #2 = item number
  % #3 = second string
  % #4 = item number
  % #5 = true text
  % #6 = false text
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \str_item:en { #1 } { #2 } } { \str_item:en { #3 } { #4 } } { #5 } { #6 }
 }

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_eq:nn { ee } { TF,T,F,p }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_item:nn { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\strA}{aaaa}
\newcommand{\strB}{bbbb}
\newcommand{\strC}{bbab}

\begin{document}

\comparestringitems{\strA}{4}{\strB}{3}{true}{false}

\comparestringitems{\strA}{4}{\strC}{3}{true}{false}

\edef\test{\comparestringitems{\strA}{4}{\strC}{3}{true}{false}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Both of your answers produces some errors in my machine (Texlive 2018):

Comment: Second code error: `: LaTeX error: "kernel/invalid-variant" Variant form 'ee' invalid for base form '\str_if_eq:nnTF'.
: LaTeX error: "kernel/invalid-variant" Variant form 'ee' invalid for base form '\str_if_eq:nnT'. 
: LaTeX error: "kernel/invalid-variant" Variant form 'ee' invalid for base form '\str_if_eq:nnF'. 
: LaTeX error: "kernel/invalid-variant" Variant form 'ee' invalid for base form '\str_if_eq_p:nn'. 
: LaTeX error: "kernel/invalid-variant" Variant form 'e' invalid for base form '\str_item:nn'. 
line 28: Undefined control sequence. ..ringitems{\strA}{4}{\strB}{3}{true}{false}`

Comment: First Code errors: `: LaTeX error: "kernel/invalid-variant" Variant form 'ee' invalid for base form '\str_if_eq:nnTF'. 
: LaTeX error: "kernel/invalid-variant" Variant form 'ee' invalid for base form '\str_if_eq:nnT'.
: LaTeX error: "kernel/invalid-variant" Variant form 'ee' invalid for base form '\str_if_eq:nnF'.
: LaTeX error: "kernel/invalid-variant" Variant form 'ee' invalid for base form '\str_if_eq_p:nn'.
line 34 36 42: Undefined control sequence.`

Comment: @C.F.G Update your TeX system